# Delete all comments from asp.net project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

i have a project for maintenance where is so much random comments code. I wants to delete but its takes so much time is there is a solutions to remove comments code from my project thanks.

Comment: hi thanks but i am looking for visual studio 2012 or 2013

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may replace the comments with search and replace in files (ctrl-h) using regular expressions. (There is a small button in the search and replace dialog, near the buttons for "match case" and "match whole word" to enable regular expressions)

For a // comment for example, you may replace "[\s]*//.*" with "", which replaces all lines containing "//" to the end of line, optional beginning with a whitespace with an empty string ("").

For more information about regex you may have a look at this site http://regexone.com/lesson/9

If you are new to regular expressions, you should always have a working backup of your files :-)

Comment: This expression should basically match a /* */ comment along multiple lines "(?s)[\s]*/\*.*\*/"

Comment: Not backup but a proper version control system eg. Git with frequent commits. A simple backup won't help when you are halfway through replacement and find that you need to undo the replacements eg. in the last 3 files

Comment: Also there's no regex (or any other method) that can differentiate commented code from actual comments. The OP will still have to inspect each replacement. Regex will make it easier and faster to find the comments